# How do I make a sideways L look in html/css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I know the title wasn't the best way to describe it.  But I am trying to recreate the symbols shown in the image on both sides of the word interval.  I have no idea how to do this.  Is it a symbol?  Or some kind of graphic using svg?

Comment: Without more details it’s kinda hard to say exactly how it’s done...

Comment: what kind of details?

Comment: What website is this on? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the source code to investigate?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, users posting a question are supposed to make an effort of their own, which you clearly haven't. Reread [ask]

Comment: This question is considered too broad for SO. I’d recommend reading the [help] so you can learn about the site’s guidelines

Comment: Why don't you just inspect the code from the page you're seeing this on and see how they did it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution,

You can use **border-width** to create that shape

To create the first **L** shape, make top and left border-width 2px.

Similarly for 2nd **L** shape make border-width of  top and right 2px;

```css
span:after,span:before{
    content: "";
    width: 41px;
    height: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
      border:1px solid grey;
}

span:after{
  border-width:2px 2px 0 0; /*top right bottom left*/
}

span:before{
  border-width:2px 0 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<span>Interval</span>
```